# Subtracting from CGFloat

Tags: iphone, ios, floating-point, cgfloat

```
NSLog(@"original float value = %f", [anNSNumber floatValue]);
                 
float newFloat = [anNSNumber floatValue] - 1.0f;
                 
NSLog(@"newFloat = %f", newFloat);
```

Gives me

> orginal float value = 215987480044765184.000000
>
> newFloat = 215987480044765184.000000

How do you simply subtract 1 from a `float`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot simplify it further. Floating point number is different from integer.

Another thing to note is that `float` type can only contain up to 24 bit of precision (around 6-7 decimal digits of precision). The number you have there exceeds the precision available for `float`, and the subtraction amount is too small to affect in the 24 bit of precision, so the operation simply **does not make any change to the result**.

The problem is not fixed even if you do the operation in `double`, since the number even exceeds the 53 bit precision for `double`.

Depends on your requirement, a 64-bit integer type (`long long` type, or more specific `int64_t`) may be what you need. If such precision is necessary for even bigger number, basic type won't be sufficient. External library may be needed if you need very high precision.

Comment: One day I will understand floats. Thanks, will try integers now.

Comment: Ah, ints though are too small.

Comment: So how do you minus 1 from a large NSNumber?

Comment: @daidai: Use `longLongValue` to get the 64-bit number from NSNumber, and assign it to a `long long` variable, or `int64_t` variable (make it unsigned if it is some sort of ID: `unsigned long long` and `uint64_t`), then work on the variable as you would with an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have on your 3rd line: NSLog(@"newFloat = %f", **idOfLastTweet**); instead of NSLog(@"newFloat = %f", **newFloat**); ?

Comment: Changed. This is for Twitter, but wanted to make the example more generic.